# How to return non blade based view in laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-7

I have custom php file (`index.php` and not `index.blade.php`) with HTML & PHP codes. How I can use this file as view in laravel and return it?

I tried like this but not work:

```
Return view("index.php");
```

Comment: Rename it to `index.blade.php`?!

Comment: put it in the public folder and access it in domain/index.php

Comment: I tried already rename it but laravel return error `Action Facade\Ignition\Http\Controllers\ExecuteSolutionController not defined.`. Because I've inside my file php functions and many php code. @kerbholz

Comment: Why I must close this question?

Comment: @user10971804 There already is Laravel's `index.php` in the `public` folder

Comment: @kerbholz you could change the name to anything it's still accessible

Comment: @AndreasHunter Adapt your script to Laravel. Extract your functions to Controllers/Models/Helpers, use your HTML as layout file/convert to blade. You don't have to close this question, someone suggested to close it, probably because it lacks effort from your side/requires more information.

Comment: @user10971804 True, you could, but that's not what you commented

Comment: @kerbholz How is that not answering the question?

Comment: @user10971804 OP asked how to return it as a `view` in Laravel, not how to display it

Comment: @ kerbholz So what's the final output in that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I have custom php file (index.php and not index.blade.php) with HTML & PHP codes. How I can use this file as view in laravel and return it?

I would strongly recommend to use [Laravel's Blade Engine](https://laravel.com/docs/blade) and stick to the [MVC](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model_View_Controller) principle of separating your view from your business logic.

However, if you have to use a custom PHP file instead, then you could do it like this:

```
class YourController extends Controller
{    
   public function index() 
   {
      $content = require 'path/to/your/index.php'; 
      return $content;
   }   

}
```

If your path leads to the resource directory you could use the [resource_path](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/helpers#method-resource-path) helper:

```
$content = require resource_path('views/index.php');
```

Comment: Does the path work inside the resources folder?

Comment: @user10971804 in my case work with like this path inside `Controllers` folder of framework. Code:  `$content = require '../resources/views/index.php';`

Comment: @AndreasHunter there is a helper function in Laravel for that. You could use `$content = require resource_path('views/index.php');`

Comment: Thanks for help with path @Adam

Answer (score -1):

Laravel Already have index.php file in `public / index.php`
Try renaming it to something else and try it .